# React JS - Best practice to hide http call credentials

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What's the best practices to hide or prevent the user see the credentials (implemented in WebService calls). The development is ReactJS and use Heroku to deploy the WebApp.

I have this code:
[image]

I want to prevent the user can see the credentials and some security details.

Comment: You should make the requests server-side. Usually the best practice is to store sensitive information as environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Do you have an example how to define environment variables in NodeJS/ReactJS?

Comment: I use this - https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv. But again, it would probably be best to make your API calls server-side. Not sure what specific resource you're requesting. But there's a good chance it would prevent it from being done client-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started using the node module [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) recently and really like how easy it is to use. All you need to do is install it and create a `.env` file with your environment variables like this:

**.env**

```
SECRET_KEY=123456
ANOTHER_KEY=78901
```

Then, require it as early as possible in your application:

`require('dotenv').config()`.

I do this inside my `server.js` file (or whatever you name it).

That's it! Anything stored in the file can now be accessed by doing `process.env.{name}`

For example:

```
let secret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
console.log(secret); // 123456
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will not work on react-native tho. I think OP is trying to say that he wants to hide URLs etc in react-native and not from the server

Comment: pretty sure this will also be accessible from the console. So not very secure

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible to do in a client side because all the HTTP calls can be easily visible in Network tab in Chrome Inspect Elements(or any web browser).

I would suggest you work on the security so you don't care if a user will see your HTTP endpoints or not.

You can also consider making your HTTP request on a server which will act as a bridge between your client and an API.